# Azure Data Factory / Aggregate as comma separated string

Tags: azure, ssis, etl, azure-data-factory, data-transform

I want to aggregate by data using `Aggregate`.

Here is the scenario:

I've a table having values as below:

```
Key | Value
1   | v1
1   | v2
2   | v1
2   | v3
```

After performing aggregation, I want output as below:

```
Key | Value
1   | v1, v2
2   | v1, v3
```

I tried to find `String_Agg` function which is not available in ADF.

Comment: Data aggregation can be done in ADF via data flow , take a look at below docs from Microsoft to understand better about this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow

Comment: I did the same. I'm using Mapping data flow but I'm not able to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faced the same issue recently. I ended up sinking the table, then creating a new dataflow that would query that table using SQL GROUP BY and STRING_AGG().

**MAY 2020 update:**

Microsoft released a new feature - collect transformation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#collect 
It can be used in aggregation step and produce an array with the values you need. It can be then followed by the derived column step to cast the string array toString().

Comment: My pleasure, I just wish there was an easier solution in ADF :)

Comment: Yes, it should. I feel that it's a workaround that we did.

Comment: Actually, looks like last week, Microsoft released a new feature - collect aggregation:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/adf-adds-new-hierarchical-data-handling-and-new-flexibility-for/ba-p/1353956#
using it in combination with derived column might do the trick.

Comment: That's good to know. If you could provide the sample as an answer, then it'll be helpful for other people. Thanks!